# 2-dim random variable $(X,Y)$ with $0 < x < y < 1$

Tags: probability, random-variables

The 2-dimensional random variable $(X,Y)$ has the pdf

$$f_{X,Y}(x, y) = \begin{cases} 
\ 12(y - x)^2, & \text{si } 0 < x < y < 1 \\
 0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

We must compute $P(Y>1/2)$. As the range of $x$ depends on $y$ and vice-versa, I don't know if the ranges of my integrals in the formula for this result should be {1/2 to 1 for $y$ and 0 to 1 for $x$} or {1/2 to 1 for $y$ and 0 to $y$ for $x$} or neither of these. Could someone explain the impact of the ranges of $x$ and $y$ :$ 0 < x < y < 1 $?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the best approach to these integrals is to use indicator functions. So we write $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 12(x-y)^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{0<x<y<1\}}.$ Then
$$
\begin{align*}
P(Y > 1/12) &= \int\limits_{\mathbf{R}^2} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \mathbf{1}_{\{y > 1/2\}} d(x,y) \\
&= \int\limits_{\mathbf{R}^2} 12(x-y)^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{0<y<1\}} \mathbf{1}_{\{0<x<y\}} \mathbf{1}_{\{y>1/2\}} d(x,y)\\
&= \int\limits_{1/2}^1 dy \int\limits_0^y dx\ 12(x-y) = \ldots,
\end{align*}
$$
remembering that the impact of an indicator function $a<x<b$ is to set the limits of integrations $a$ and $b.$ An clear advantage of the use of indicator in integrals is that the method is algebraic and it applies to any number of dimensions. The geometric versions usually fail to replicate in any number of dimensions greater than 2, and in 2 dimensions they will get messy to visualise should the indicator functions contain strange domains (i.e., not squares, rectangles, triangles, semicircles, etc.).